# User Configuration GPO for Microsoft Edge to set homepages

Tags: group-policy, windows-10, homepage

I have done a fair amount of searching and have only come up with a single solution which, in my view, is not granular enough.

I am looking for a user configuration GPO for Edge to set homepages based on the users logging in. So far, all I have been able to find is a computer configuration. Is there a reg hack I can use instead to apply this per user rather than machine?

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion as you, there are virtually zero support for user-enforced GPO's when it comes to Edge. We're working on implementing Chrome instead, as it has GPO templates for just about any setting, where it all can be forced or just defaults.

Comment: Similarly we have already implemented chrome but require some support for all other installed browsers, namely edge and IE. There is a chrome gpo I have been meaning to ask about actually so may form another question for that one.